# ServiceStack F# dotnet core 3.1 example

Tags: f#, servicestack

There is an [example](https://docs.servicestack.net/fsharp) of a simple ServiceStack F# application for .NET 4.5:

```
open System
open ServiceStack

type Hello = { mutable Name: string; }
type HelloResponse = { mutable Result: string; }
type HelloService() =
    interface IService
    member this.Any (req:Hello) = { Result = "Hello, " + req.Name }

//Define the Web Services AppHost
type AppHost =
    inherit AppSelfHostBase
    new() = { inherit AppSelfHostBase("Hi F#!", typeof<HelloService>.Assembly) }
    override this.Configure container =
        base.Routes
            .Add<Hello>("/hello")
            .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name}") |> ignore

//Run it!
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let host = if args.Length = 0 then "http://*:1337/" else args.[0]
    printfn "listening on %s ..." host
    let appHost = new AppHost()
    appHost.Init() |> ignore
    appHost.Start host |> ignore
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

I'm trying to play with F# for the first time, F# examples on a page above are a bit outdated.

I've tried to rewrite [this dotnet core 3.1 C# self-host example](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/selfhost/blob/master/MyApp/Program.cs) to F# and here is my version which doesn't work because of:

```
app.Run(context =>
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/metadata");
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });
```

Full dotnet core 3.1 F# self-host example which doesn't work because of an error in corespondent to above's F# code:

```
namespace MyApp

open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open ServiceStack.Text
open System.Diagnostics
open ServiceStack
open ServiceStack.Common
open System
open System.IO
open System.Reflection
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open Funq
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

type Hello = { mutable Name: string; }
type HelloResponse = { mutable Result: string; }
type HelloService() =
    interface IService
    member this.Any (req:Hello) = { Result = "Hello, " + req.Name }

type AppHost =
    inherit AppHostBase
    new() = { inherit AppHostBase("Hi F#!", typeof<HelloService>.Assembly) }
    override this.Configure (container : Container)  =
        base.Routes
            .Add<Hello>("/hello")
            .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name}") |> ignore

type Startup() =
    inherit ModularStartup()
        
        /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        /// For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        member this.ConfigureServices(services : IServiceCollection ) =
            ()
        
        /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        member this.Configure(app : IApplicationBuilder (*, env : IWebHostEnvironment *) ) =
            app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost())
            app.Run(
                       fun context ->
                           context.Response.Redirect("/metadata")
                           Task.FromResult(0)
                   )

module Main =
    open System
        [<EntryPoint>]
        let main argv =
            let host = new WebHostBuilder()
            host.UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000/")
                .UseModularStartup<Startup>()
                .Build()
                .Run()
            0
```

Can anyone help with core 3.1 F# example for a simple self-host console application like the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an empty .NET Core 3.1 Project Template that you can download in a new empty directory using the [x dotnet tool](https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-tool) which will let you start a new F# .NET Core 3.1. ServiceStack Project with:

```
$ dotnet tool install --global x 
$ md ProjectName && cd ProjectName
$ x mix init-fsharp
$ dotnet run
```

Which will download the [init-fsharp Gist](https://gist.github.com/gistlyn/4802ba22b665e68c7257aef9f57c1934) to your local directory.

Comment: But strange happens in `Program.fs` and `async` becomes not allowed whenever `open ServiceStack` is used.  For example https://gist.github.com/zelid/fdf5e53544f9c979e91b492bdaf01aae gives an error: https://monosnap.com/direct/R2AXV88rRLec57OyuhrOplYXIueaNA in comparison to https://monosnap.com/direct/P2OccIgct22kLbdMBVj0HxfifELZHL

Comment: @Zelid No idea why it's affecting the F# compiler but you'll only be able to use .NET defacto async `Task` Type in ServiceStack Services which is incompatible with F#'s async, the easiest way to use Tasks is to use [TaskBuilder.fs](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs). I've a gRPC F# client example that uses this at [NetCoreApps/todo-world/fsharp-generic](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/todo-world/tree/master/src/clients/fsharp-generic).